# AIG Global Expatriate Assistance program

Tags: credit-history, credit-cards

AIG has this program targeted at new immigrants to the US, especially those who don't have any credit history. With a sign up fee of 440$, it's supposed to help us to get unsecured credit card, mortgage, car insurance (at decent price), etc.

I'm having trouble deciding whether to opt for this program. What,  What are the alternatives? Can I "build credit history" through other means?

Also, how much of a credit history (e.g. in terms of months) would I gain by starting US life with an unsecured card instead of prepaid cards?

Comment: Isn't this a shopping question?

Comment: This is about building US credit history. I'm trying to understand the value of having a regular credit card instead of starting with those prepaid cards. Asking if this worths those 440$.

Comment: I'll try to edit this question to make answers less opinion-based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I just applied to some companies which offer credit for US immigrants. I tried Advancial and CreditStacks, and was approved in a few days for CreditStacks, which gave me a 5k limit, based on my job position and salary.

In the end, it's all about how much you spend. The problem with secured cards is that you would have to deposit a large amount to spend 30% of this amount (which is the recommended credit ratio), which means that 70% of your credit line would be idle money.